# Dapper-Plus BulkInsert - How to return number of rows affected?

Tags: bulkinsert, dapper-plus

In [Dapper-Plus](https://zzzprojects.github.io/dapper-tutorial-dev/bulk-insert), is there a way to return the number of rows affected in the database?  This is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection")))
{
    connection.BulkInsert(myList);
}
```

I see you can do it for inserting a single row, but can't find functionality on the dapper plus bulk insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dapper Plus allow to chain multiple methods, the method doesn't directly return this value.

However, you can do it with the following code:

```
var resultInfo = new Z.BulkOperations.ResultInfo();

connection.UseBulkOptions(options => {
    options.UseRowsAffected = true;
    options.ResultInfo = resultInfo;
}).BulkInsert(orders);

// Show RowsAffected
Console.WriteLine("Rows Inserted: " + resultInfo.RowsAffectedInserted);
Console.WriteLine("Rows Affected: " + resultInfo.RowsAffected);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOMNng

Keep in mind that using that option will slightly make the bulk operations slower.

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> will it make it as slow as using the regular dapper insert method or is this way still faster?

It will still be way faster than regular `Insert`.

Comment: will it make it as slow as using the regular dapper insert method or is this way still faster?